# Crontab behaves differently when running command

Tags: bash, cron

So i have this script on a raspberry pi that collects information from pi including External IP Address and Local interfaces IP Addresses and echoes them into it fsends to a remote pi.
When i manually run the script it works just great but when crontab runs it, the last bit that echoes my local interface IP addresses doesn't work, any ideas why?

Here is the code. Its not as DRY as you would expect, i am new to bash programming, i welcome any suggestions for improvement

```
#!/bin/bash
ip2=$(wget -qO- ifconfig.me/ip)
hn=$(hostname)
up=$(uptime)
datetime=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")
filename="${hn}-${datetime}"


ifaces=()
iface_addr=()
iface_types=("eth" "wlan")
for (( count=0; count<${#iface_types[@]}; count ++ )); do
    iface_type=${iface_types[count]}
    iface_number=$(ifconfig | grep ${iface_type} | wc -l)



    for (( i=0;i<iface_number; i++ )); do
        ifaces+=("${iface_type}${i}")
        ipadd=$(ifconfig | grep -A1 "${iface_type}${i}" | sed -n '2p' | xargs | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}" | head -1)
        iface_addr+=($ipadd)
    done
done

#Populate File to be sent
echo "$hn $d" > ${filename}
echo "$up" >> ${filename}
echo "External IP: ${ip2}" >> ${filename}
echo >> ${filename}
echo "Local Interfaces" >> ${filename}

for((i=0;i<${#ifaces[@]};i++)); do #This is the part that isnt included when using crontab
    echo "${ifaces[$i]}: ${iface_addr[$i]}" >> ${filename}
done

#Send Fiel TO server
./sctony -f ${filename}

#Place file on log folder
ls | grep wd.d
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    mv ${filename} wd.d
else 
    mkdir wd.d
    mv ${filename} wd.d
fi
```

Comment: I meant echoes them into a file

Comment: Show your cronjob line.

Comment: Btw, take a look at [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: This is just a guess, but it might be a problem with `$PATH`. Does it help if you include the full path to each instance if `ifconfig`, e.g. `/sbin/ifconfig`?

Comment: When I faced such crontab inconsistency in the past, it always came down to a different environment in use by cron.  I would suggest dumping your environment in the script, and run it both ways.  I bet that will help you home in on the cause.

Comment: my cronjob line is

*/5 * * * * /home/pi/wd2

Comment: How do i set the correct environmental variabla?

Comment: Although its kinda odd that it would work half way through the script. because the arrays are just the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well thank you Lithis, your answer proved to be the perfect solution. By using the full path to the command ifconfig i was able to have the same result as a manual run.